# How to fix or avoid CVE-2018-14335 H2 Security Issue?

Tags: spring-boot, h2, nexus-iq

In my Spring Boot 2 Project, I use H2 in memory Database.

My Nexus IQ Security Scan alerting about CVE-2018-14335. I dont understand the cause of this, so I cant fix it. I also dont understand the Explanation by Nexus-IQ.

- Webconsole is deactivated
- Newest H2 Version is used
- Spring Boot 2.6.6 is used

Can someone explain me in a easy language what exactly the problem is and or how to fix it in Spring Boot?

Comment: The check is, as often, flawed. It checks transitive dependencies and probably one of those depends on an older H2 version. Could even be Spring Boot as 2.6 still uses H2 1.4 and not the newest H2 v2 (which breaks backwards compatibility).

Comment: This vulnerability only affects faulty applications with H2 Console from H2 1.4.197 or older version opened for everyone (H2 Console by default doesn't allow remote access, a special configuration is needed), so your application isn't affected by it.